# EditText with negative number and TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

I have a problem with inputting negative int into my EditText, when I do so I get an error `09-12 06:26:42.025: E/AndroidRuntime(18247): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "-"`
xml file:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/downAndDistanceStarting"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/enterText" >
```

java code:

```
end = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.downAndDistanceEnding);
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
int w = Integer.parseInt(end.getText().toString());
}
```

I'm assuming there is a problem with my textWatcher and it is "sending" my input after every keyboard "press", so when I'm trying to input -12 it sends "-" for "parsening" before I manage to finish, and that's why my app is crashing, am I right? any one knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct. Wrap your code in try/catch block, then, when - is received it will throw NumberFormatException and it will be catched.

```
try
{
int w = Integer.parseInt(end.getText().toString());
}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I put a if condition before it is parsing. Like this, So till you enter the second digit it will not parse.

```
end = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.downAndDistanceEnding);
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  if(!end.getText().toString().equals("-"));
  {
    int w = Integer.parseInt(end.getText().toString());
  } else { //do something  }
}
```